# Equally spacing content inside a material-ui Grid item

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I'm using material-ui's Grid component, inside a ListItem.  I'm trying to work out how to spread three columns worth of content across four columns of the material-ui layout, as follows:

[image]

Green lines indicate five of the twelve columns. In the first one is the red icon (ignore the margin to its left). That's clear.  But then there are three pieces of content  - Name, DOB, and an ID -- that are spread across the remaining four columns shown.  The yellow lines indicate spacing between the three content pieces, which is supposed to be 1.5 rem.

I've forked a relevant material-ui demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9plyk8rrq)

If Grid items are the elements to be placed inside a Grid container, how do you handle spacing content inside an item?

EDIT: I've realized that a Grid container can indeed be nested inside a grid item, and have updated the codepen link to reflect that. What I now need to know is how to specify 1.5 rem in between each of the three content pieces. Their widths should be fixed such that the columns are respected even if the content piece is missing (e.g. there is no date -- the columns still need to stay in alignment)

Any help appreciated!